# Using Yandex Map Without API

Tags: projection, epsg, yandex, yandex-api

I want to write a map server using yandex map tiles. I need :

*BoundingBox of world (in meters)
*Size of tile at zoom level 0(in meters) 
*EPSG code that yandex map use

Is there anyone who know these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot use Yandex Map without api.
In all other cases yandex tiles look like google tiles. Except they use a bit other projection - mercator wgs84